# C# run part of a method with time interval

Tags: c#

I'm making C# application for click links of a webpage. But I want to do it with time interval. I mean link must click one second after another after next, like that. I make it but it click all links without time interval. I want to get all the links only onetime and click with interval. If I use timer class it will get links every time it elapse.
Here is my C# code. I tried different ways but none of them was success. Can u help me?

```
public void linkinvo()
{
    int clickedobj = 0;
    HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A");
    for (int i = 0; i < elems.Count; i++)
    {
        String inhref = elems[i].GetAttribute("href");
        String innerdoc = elems[i].InnerText;

        textBox2.AppendText(inhref + " -->" + innerdoc + Environment.NewLine);
        Thread.Sleep(1000); //i know this is not work 
        /* I want to run if part of this method with 1 second delay but not all the script */     

        if (innerdoc == "Like")
        {
            elems[i].InvokeMember("Click");
            clickedobj = clickedobj + 1;
        }
    }
    label3.Text = clickedobj.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** You are not `iterating` the `link` execution process.
**Solution :**

**Step 1:** You need to take the `Array of links` to be executed.
**Step 2:** Subscribe to `Timer Tick` event.
**Step 3:** Set the `Interval` property of the `Timer` to 1000 milliseconds for raising the evnt for every 1 Second.
**Step 4:** In `Tick Event Handler`  just invoke the `next link` from the `LinkArray`. and increment the `linkExecutionCount`  variable.
**Step 5:** Repeat Step 4 untill `linkExecutionCount`  reaches the `Length` of `LinkArray`.
**Step 6:** once if the `linkExecutionCount` Equals `LinkArray` length `Stop` the timer.

Try This: i have provided Sample Code on how to deal with mutilple Links

```
    String [] LinkArray=new String[]{"link1","link2","link3"};
    int linkExecutionCount=0;

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer1.Interval=1000;//one second
    timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Start();


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if(linkExecutionCount == LinkArray.Length)
            {
              timer1.Stop();
            }
           else
           {
               //execute/open link
               Open Link --->  LinkArray[linkExecutionCount]
               //increment linkExecutionCount
                linkExecutionCount++;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on similar problem multiple times
I would suggest to use timer, you can always stop it, so it wont loop
after you will stop it, thus the part you need to run after 1 second should be in
(let say) timer 1, and if there is another 3rd link then start timer 2 from timer 1
them immediately in next line, stop timer 1, thus timer 1 will handle first link click
then it will start timer 2, and after starting timer 2, timer 1 will stop

I would highly recommend as per my experience with controlling actions in win forms
with browser control